# Multilevel drop-down in mootols

Tags: javascript, nested, block, mootools

i have some issue i'm new in javascript and can't handle with multilevel nested blocks: I need to open nested block using toogle and mootools. I found some examples like accorodion, but i need toogle effect on nested blocks.
 Can you help me?
Thanks.
1) here example  that i found on jquery, i need the same but on mootools

```js
$('.nested-accordion').find('.comment').slideUp();
$('.nested-accordion').find('h3').click(function(){
  $(this).next('.comment').slideToggle(100);
  $(this).toggleClass('selected');
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-family: Calibri, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 80%;
}

.nested-accordion {
  margin-top: 0.5em;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.nested-accordion h3 {
  padding: 0 0.5em;
}
.nested-accordion .comment {
  line-height: 1.5;
  padding: 0.5em;
}
.nested-accordion h3 {
  color: #47a3da;
}
.nested-accordion h3:before {
  content: "+";
  padding-right: 0.25em;
  color: #becbd2;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-family: "Lucida Console", Monaco, monospace;
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
}
.nested-accordion h3.selected {
  background: #47a3da;
  color: #fff;
}
.nested-accordion h3.selected:before {
  content: "-";
}
.nested-accordion .comment {
  color: #768e9d;
  border: 0.063em solid #47a3da;
  border-top: none;
}
.nested-accordion a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #47a3da;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class='nested-accordion'>
    <h3>Heading</h3>
    <div class='comment'>
      This is a comment 
      <div class='nested-accordion'>
        <h3>Heading</h3>
        <div class='comment'>
          This is a another content which is really long and pointless but keeps on going and it technically a run-on sentence but here is a link to google to distract you -> <a href='http://google.com' target='_blank'>link</a>
          <div class='nested-accordion'>
            <h3>Heading</h3>
            <div class='comment'>This is a another content</div>
          </div>
          <div class='nested-accordion'>
            <h3>Heading</h3>
            <div class='comment'>This is a another content</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='nested-accordion'>
        <h3>Heading</h3>
        <div class='comment'>This is a another content</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='nested-accordion'>
    <h3>Heading</h3>
    <div class='comment'>This is a another content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

One Mootools function I like is Reveal.

This can reveal up/down or left/right.

element.toggle() will snap to the opposite state (if open, will close without animating, etc). Otherwise, element.reveal() or element.dissolve() will open / close.

In your case, you would want something like:

```
var container = document.getElement('.container');
Array.each(container.getElements('.comment'), function(comment){
  comment.set('reveal', {duration: 250}).toggle();
  if(comment.getPrevious('h3')){
    comment.getPrevious('h3').addEvent('click', function(e){
      var comment = e.target.getNext('.comment');
      if(comment.getStyle('display')==='block'){
        e.target.getNext('.comment').dissolve();
      }else{
        e.target.getNext('.comment').reveal();
      }
    });
  }
});
```

I am using Mootools long hand methods here (avoiding dollar) so that you can play nice with other frameworks (like jQuery).

The Mootools docs are pretty good, but may take some trial and error ;)

[Mootools Reveal](http://mootools.net/more/docs/1.6.0/Fx/Fx.Reveal)

Here is an example with your HTML / CSS:

[JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/cpqkdt4x/)

I hope this helps!